# Suppose $f_n$ are $\tau$-periodic and converges uniformly to $f$. Is $f$ also $\tau$-periodic?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

Suppose $f_n$ are $\tau$-periodic for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and converges uniformly to $f$. Is $f$ also $\tau$-periodic?

I was thinking that this could maybe be shown using pointwise convergence but I can't quite make it work. Perhaps you also need to assume continuity?

Comment: $f_n(x+ \tau) = f_n(x)$ for all $n$: What does that tell you about the limit function $f$?

Comment: Ah so $f(x + \tau) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x + \tau) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x) $. Thank you!

Comment: You just need pointwise convergence, not uniform.